# Regex find CamelCase strings and dashes, replace with lowercase_underscored

Tags: regex, phpstorm

In PHPStorm, I need to find/replace some mixed case strings which are used for CSS class names and for the DOM id's. I can't change attributes like `onClick` and image names need to remain. Here is what I have:

```
<div class="ThumbContainer" id="Source-Data4-Thumb">
<div class="ThumbTitleArea">
    <div class="DataTitleDiv"> GYR Performance <img src="images/someImage.png" onClick="someFunc()" /></div>
</div>
    <div class="dataDetailArea">
    <div class="DataThumbArea"> Data Source:Client<br>
                    Last refreshed:12/05/2013 <br>
                    Records:206<br>
        <br>
                        Used for the following reports<br>
                -    GYR Performance<br>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is what I need:

```
<div class="thumb_container" id="source_data4_thumb">
<div class="thumb_title_area">
    <div class="data_title_div"> GYR Performance <img src="images/someImage.png" onClick="someFunc()" /></div>
</div>
    <div class="data_detail_area">
    <div class="data_thumb_area"> Data Source:Client<br>
                      Last refreshed:12/05/2013 <br>
                      Records:206<br>
        <br>
                          Used for the following reports<br>
                 -    GYR Performance<br>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Notice the `dataDetailArea` starts with a lowercase.. bleh. This will be a one-time find/replace so it doesn't need to be in PHPStorm. It can be in any online tool even, like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

The actual backbone template I need to find/replace on is about 3100 lines of code, otherwise I'd provide it all here for you.

Here's what I have so far. It seems to not match match the `Camel-Case3-Foo`:

```
(class|id|data-[?!=])="\b([A-Za-z][a-z-]*){2,}\b"
```

Comment: Which regex are you using? bash, java, c#, vi, emacs, VS2010? There are some differences.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect tags. Those seem to have carried over from my last question and I didn't notice! :(

Comment: It's PHPStorm find/replace. I'm not sure which version JetBrains uses. Does this help? http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html

Comment: Before doing the regex, you should use an HTML parser to separate out the classes and id's, or you could end up changing content within the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should find the locations where underscores should be placed:

```
((?<=\w)(?=[A-Z])|-)
```

It would seem to make sense to do a replacement with this to insert the underscores, then convert the string to lower case.

Comment: This is not working for me. It seems to only match the dashes.

Comment: Sorry, edited my answer. This should match dashes and the space between a character and upper-case character.

Comment: Ah I see, it wasn't highlighting the matches like it was on my other attempts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would search for something like this:

```
"[a-z0-9_]*\([A-Z]\)
```

A quote mark with anything following that has lowercase, numeric, or underscore characters.
Anything following that has an uppercase letter.
Make the uppercase letter sub-expression 1.

Replace subexpression 1 with an underscore + the result from a tolower() function.

You will need to apply this multiple times to each line since it will only find one
uppercase letter per pass.

Comment: Not sure you'd want to match the underscore (Date_Range becomes date__range?)

Comment: this might fail if you have this:  <tag "stuff"A   Hopefully your html isn't minified.

Comment: You need the underscore if there are multiple upper case letters. if it replaces the first instance of 'myStuffHere' with "my_stuffHere" then later passes will fail without it

Comment: perhaps `"[^"]*[a-z0-9]\([A-Z]\)` would be more appropriate then?

Comment: Thanks Jay! Please see my updated question - hopefully it's more cut and dry. I think my original question might have been vague and I apologize.